# Display the blank page on the SEARCH TERMS page

Tags: magento-2.1, search-terms

I can see some search queries on MARKETING, SEO & SEARCH, Search Terms of the admin page. However, the SEARCH TERMS page of frontend displays the blank.

Some people mentioned hat this error happens in version 2.1 even though it works in version 2.0.7.

I appreciate if you give advice or solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appears to be a bug in 2.1. The code is trying to get the "name" of the search term when it should be asking for the "query_text."

You can get it to work by updating the following two files:

---

File `Magento/Search/Block/Term.php`.

```
94. $temp[$term->getName()] = $term;
94. $temp[$term->getData('query_text')] = $term;

95. $termKeys[] = $term->getName();
95. $termKeys[] = $term->getData('query_text');

127. $url->setQueryParam('q', $obj->getName());
127. $url->setQueryParam('q', $obj->getData('query_text'));
```

---

File `Magento/Search/view/frontend/templates/term.phtml`.

```
16. escapeHtml($_term->getName()) ?>
16. escapeHtml($_term->getData('query_text')) ?>
```

Comment: @Mig Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

can you provide a link to the site where the search is executed? It will be helpful)

Alos, try to run the search when you logged in, logged out, from the private tab in your browser, etc.